# Problem with node position

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Why the last node, named `kap2`, does not change its position when I replace `at (1,0)` by `at (3,0)`? [I want to change the position of the comment "Killing vectors"]

My MWE:

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{mathtools,tikz,lmodern, xparse}
    \usepackage{tensor}
    \usetikzlibrary{%arrows, chains, matrix, 
                positioning, 
                %shadows,
                shapes, shapes.callouts,graphs, calc,
                %shapes.geometric,
                %shapes.misc                    
                }


    \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]  

    \begin{document}


    \begin{frame}{}
               \begin{equation*}
                   g_{ik}(\phi)\partial_j\tikz[baseline=0.18cm,overlay] \node[name=kap] at (0.18,0.3){$\kappa^k$};\phantom{\kappa^k}
                          +g_{mj}(\phi)\partial_i\kappa^m+\kappa^n \partial_n g_{ij}(\phi)=0
               \end{equation*}  
              \tikz  \node[draw,  right,name=kap2,rounded corners,  fill=red!20,align=left] at (1,0) {Killing vectors};
              \tikz[overlay] \draw[red,->] (kap2) to (kap); 
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add overlay  key in :

```
 \tikz  \node[draw,  right,name=kap2,rounded corners, overlay,
          fill=red!20,align=left] at (3,-2) {Killing vectors};
```

Don't forget to compile twice !

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{mathtools,tikz,lmodern, xparse}
    \usepackage{tensor}
    \usetikzlibrary{%arrows, chains, matrix, 
                positioning, 
                %shadows,
                shapes, shapes.callouts,graphs, calc,
                %shapes.geometric,
                %shapes.misc                    
                }

    \begin{document}

    \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture,]  



    \begin{frame}{}
               \begin{equation*}
                   g_{ik}(\phi)\partial_j\tikz[baseline=0.18cm,overlay] \node[name=kap] at (0.18,0.3){$\kappa^k$};\phantom{\kappa^k}
                          +g_{mj}(\phi)\partial_i\kappa^m+\kappa^n \partial_n g_{ij}(\phi)=0
               \end{equation*}  

              \tikz  \node[draw,  right,name=kap2,rounded corners, overlay,
              fill=red!20,align=left] at (3,-2) {Killing vectors};
              \tikz[overlay] \draw[red,->] (kap2) to (kap); 
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In, fact this solve the problem, but I found  in the TikZ manual that the `overlay` option is obligatory only for the pictures that contain references to other pictures (as I did in the last `\tikz`)!

Comment: flav, Can you please explain to me why `overlay` is obligatory here ?

Comment: @MedVall I think that : overlay is need when you want to use the node in an another picture and you use it as the begin of the arrow (referring to section 16.13.1 of the 2.10 tikz version)

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that, thanks a lot  @flav,